# How to catch click event on a link in a new window object displaying google seach result

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to catch click event on a link from a new window object displaying google search result for the below query string.

```
<script>
    window.open("https://www.google.co.in/?#q=education+engineering");
<script>
```

I am using jsp, javascript, html for my code

Comment: Can't be done.  You open google in a new browser window, you have no control over what happens in that window (google does).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to catch an event in a different window. The JavaScript environment and DOM in that other window is sandboxed for security reasons.

Comment: consider accepting this answer if you believe it to be the correct one.